# How to derive the Cubic Interpolation algorithm?

Tags: motion-planning

I have a data point array. Which is recorded at 20Hz(0.05 second. It can be 30Hz, 40Hz, 50Hz. *20Hz is an example value*)

### [image: little t]

I want to interpolate this data to bigger frequency for example 1kHz(0.001 second) with cubic interpolation to get smooth data set. 
**y(t) = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d**

### [image: little t]

But I can't figure out how can I derive the function and implement with C.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) such as [Cubic Hermite Splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), etc. However, it really depends on how you want you path looks.

- If it is something like
  [image]

and you want something of third order (specifically, a velocity profile of third order), you can solve for a function $P_{01}(t) = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d$ which satisfies, for example,
$$
\begin{align}
P_{01}(t_0) &= x_0\\
P_{01}(t_0) &= x_1\\
P_{01}'(t_0) &= 0\\
P_{01}'(t_1) &= 0\\
P_{01}''(t_0) &= 0\\
P_{01}''(t_1) &= 0,
\end{align}
$$
where $P'$ indicates the first time derivative of $P$, etc.
You can substitute all the boundary conditions above to the function and solve for all the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. You may want to have a look at [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) and [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Note that if you change boundary conditions, you can also make the path looks smooth (i.e., not so zigzaggy).

- If you just want a straight line between two consecutive points, you can even do
  $$
  P_{01}(t) = x_0 + \left(\frac{x_1 - x_0}{t_1 - t_0}\right)(t - t_0).
  $$

You don't need to use higher-order polynomials.

- If you, instead, want something like
  [image]

[Spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to fit a degree three polynomial to course data to be able to use the polynomial to interpolate between the course data points.

To be able to fit the coefficients ($a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$) of the degree three polynomial so that it goes through the original data points, you need exactly four data points, $(t_1,y_1), \cdots, (t_4,y_4)$.  If you have more than four data points, the polynomial values will not necessarily go through the original data points.

**Edit: Calculation of Polynomial Coefficients**

For four sequential data points ($i,i+1,i+2,i+3$), the following equations must hold:
\begin{eqnarray}
at_i^3 +bt_i^2 +ct_i + d &=& y_i \\
at_{i+1}^3 +bt_{i+1}^2 +ct_{i+1} + d &=& y_{i+1} \\
at_{i+2}^3 +bt_{i+2}^2 +ct_{i+2} + d &=& y_{i+2} \\
at_{i+3}^3 +bt_{i+3}^2 +ct_{i+3} + d &=& y_{i+3} 
\end{eqnarray}
This can be written as a matrix-vector equation
$$
\left[\begin{array}{llll}
t_i^3 & t_i^2 & t_i & 1 \\
t_{i+1}^3 & t_{i+1}^2 & t_{i+1} & 1 \\
t_{i+2}^3 & t_{i+2}^2 & t_{i+2} & 1 \\
t_{i+3}^3 & t_{i+3}^2 & t_{i+3} & 1 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{l}
y_i \\ y_{i+1} \\ y_{i+2} \\ y_{i+3}
\end{array}\right] 
$$
which can be solved for the vector of unknown coefficients  ($a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$) using
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{llll}
t_i^3 & t_i^2 & t_i & 1 \\
t_{i+1}^3 & t_{i+1}^2 & t_{i+1} & 1 \\
t_{i+2}^3 & t_{i+2}^2 & t_{i+2} & 1 \\
t_{i+3}^3 & t_{i+3}^2 & t_{i+3} & 1 
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[\begin{array}{l}
y_i \\ y_{i+1} \\ y_{i+2} \\ y_{i+3}
\end{array}\right] 
$$
These coefficients can then be used to calculate the value of $y$ for a given $t$ where $t_i<t<t_{i+3}$:
$$
y = at_3 + bt^2 +ct +d
$$

I would recommend using a cubic spline interpolation method so that you will get a smooth interpolating curve that goes through all the original data points and that can handle more that four data points. See [Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1403886) by Press, et al. for very good C or C++ code to perform cubic spline interpolation.